# How do I create a tag synonym?

Tags: support

I'm trying to create a tag synonym: disc -> disc brake

but unclear how to do so. I should have the stats to suggest synonyms but don't know how to do so. Help?!

Update: also trying to collapse "electric" and "ebike" into "electric-bike", please vote: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tags/electric-bike/synonyms

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. I had to go to the tag description and then click on synonyms. But I don't have enough tag credit to edit synonyms.

Rant mode: It seems kind of silly to have to require a certain user score IN A TAG to suggest tag synonyms. Makes it hard to clean up the morass of tags.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you found the mechanisms available in the site. I believe the requirements for reputation within the tag is designed for sites with a *wider* focus than we have here, like computer programming (Stack Overflow).

Even if you had the required answer score on the tag, it would likely take a long while for enough other users with the required tag answer score to find the tag synonym suggestion and approve it.

So, I'd like to suggest the alternative of getting a moderator involved:

- If you *can* suggest a tag synonym, do that first; it makes the rest easier.
- If it's a completely non-controversial tag synonym, flag a post with one of the tags, give it custom text, and ask one of us mods to create the tag synonym. Or ping a mod in chat.
- If there's likely to be any kind of controversy about it at all, open up a meta post.

Since you opened up a meta post and I can't imagine a likely use of [disc](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disc) that isn't about disc brakes, I created the tag synonym and also "merged" them.

The merge means that in addition to any future [disc](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disc) turning into [disc-brake](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disc-brake), the [disc](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disc) tag was removed from all 25 questions that had it and [disc-brake](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disc-brake) was added to 19 of them.

While I was in the synonym maintenance area, I noticed a couple of tag synonym suggestions and similarly merged and created synonyms for [identification](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification)->[identify-this-bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-bike) and [aluminium](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aluminium)->[aluminum](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aluminum).

Comment: Just to note: Tag synonym aren't really appropriate here. Synonyms were intended to link two completely *different* words meaning essentially the same thing (think 'car' vs 'auto'). For simple variations on the *same* word, there's no need to bulk up the tag listings with every word inflection. Text completion will help guide the user to the correct usage: `d` `i` `s` > `disc-brake`

Comment: @RobertCartaino But somehow, at some point in time, we did have different questions tagged "disc", "disc-brake", and/or "disk-brake"...  Hard to see since they got cleaned up... And I see that on electric/electric-bike/ebike right now (though looks like some of the "electric" tagged posts are about electrical issues on bikes  that aren't an "electric-bike".) Should I have just done the tag rename without creating a synonym?

Comment: Yes, a moderator-level rename would combine tags without bumping 'activity' on the front page. Once the tags are the way you like, text completion should to guide users towards the right selection. It takes a higher reputation for users to (inadvertently) create an incorrect *close-spelling* tags, so hopefully that doesn't happen too often (editing and cleanup should take care of the occasional mis-step). But if users *consistently* keep recreating tags like [ebike] where [electronic-bike] may be preferred (just an example), then a synonym may help avoid that ongoing maintenance issue.